# PnP Cmdlets / Provisioning: What are the minimal required permissions for basic SharePoint operations?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, microsoft-graph, pnp-provision

So far I mostly used PnP provisioning with interactive login (=a user logs in) which worked fine.

I now want to PnP-provision some folders and content types using **application permissions** with the least permissions possible. Also, MS Graph should be used.

To connect I use a certificate and `clientId` of my app:

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/thesite" -Tenant "tenant.onmicrosoft.com" -ClientId <id of AAD registered app> -Thumbprint <cert thumbprint>`

It connects fine.

But I am not able to do much using PnP cmdlets. So far I tried using `Sites.ReadWrite.All` and `Sites.Manage.All` as app permission but was not able to create event a single list item using `New-PnPListItem`. Far away from `Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate`. I always get 401 errors:

> Add-PnPListItem: The remote server returned an error: (401)
> Unauthorized.

Is there a certain minimal Graph permission level that needs to be present for PnP to work at all? Is a minimal permission approach feasable when working with PnP?

I'm aware that more permissions are needed the more I want to do in SharePoint. But for SharePoint there are not so many available:
[image]

For basic stuff I'd expect `Sites.ReadWrite.All` or `Sites.Manage.All` to succeed. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose SharePoint API permissions instead of Graph permissions

[image]

Comment: This is specific to PnP, right? Because the Graph `Sites.*` permission scopes exist. It's just that PnP doesn't use them for SharePoint operations? Also, when choosing SharePoint, the UI says: "SharePoint APIs are available via the Microsoft Graph API.  You may want to consider using Microsoft Graph instead." And do I have to set up an app-only principal in this case? (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

Comment: Yes, pnp does not use Graph permissions. It's for Microsoft Graph API.(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)

Comment: You did not need to set up an SharePoint app-only. You are using AAD app-only now.(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)

Comment: Yep, works with SharePoint permissions set. Thank you!